# Internet Sharing from Mac(LAN) to iPhone USB

Tags: iphone, network, vpn, internet-sharing

I'ld like to enable internet sharing b/w my Mac iPhone. I've enabled Internet Sharing and selected VPN  and in options to computer using - I've selected iPhone USB. I'm still not able to connect to internet. My Mac is connected to internet via LAN using USB 10/100/1000 , which has port for LAN wire. Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You can share it as a password protected wi-fi network

Comment: @Harcker I don't want it as wi- fi.

Comment: But your Mac can share the VPN, in the left side of your screenshot, tick Wi-Fi, and change the settings in “Wi-Fi Options…”, then connect your iPhone to the network...

Comment: @Harcker is it not possible by USB ?

Comment: I don’t think so

Comment: @Harcker why would that be ? I was using older Mac which has port for LAN wire , then I was able to share internet via USB